# container builder timeout uploading container

Tags: google-container-builder

I am using the container registry builder.  It seems to work well.  However, I get a timeout in an unexpected place.  The timeout is in the `Preparing` stage of uploading a image.

`Pushing gcr.io/my-project/nimbl/foo
The push refers to a repository [gcr.io/my-project/nimbl/foo]
c0657b8960f1: Preparing
298d55719be3: Preparing
2c92aca44757: Preparing
456bc265a0bd: Preparing
a787b259a3da: Preparing
9f23e5ebcfc2: Preparing
dab134dd71e8: Preparing
9911896abb59: Preparing
e4a87d9fa1bb: Preparing
5881b25780f5: Preparing
da4d37ad6531: Preparing
004e69f3a081: Preparing
164d3ebb8cbe: Preparing
9f23e5ebcfc2: Waiting
dab134dd71e8: Waiting
9911896abb59: Waiting
e4a87d9fa1bb: Waiting
5881b25780f5: Waiting
da4d37ad6531: Waiting
004e69f3a081: Waiting
164d3ebb8cbe: Waiting
a787b259a3da: Pushed
298d55719be3: Pushed
456bc265a0bd: Pushed
c0657b8960f1: Pushed
dab134dd71e8: Pushed
9f23e5ebcfc2: Pushed
9911896abb59: Pushed
5881b25780f5: Pushed
da4d37ad6531: Pushed
004e69f3a081: Pushed
164d3ebb8cbe: Pushed`

`Your build timed out. Use the [--timeout=DURATION] flag to change the timeout threshold.
ERROR: (gcloud.container.builds.submit) build e21dc778-8f29-49e9-a17c-a9d52a5cc982 completed with status "TIMEOUT"`

I have tried increasing the timeout without success.  It never seems to leave the preparing stage.